# Mkbundle doesn't work for simple program

Tags: mono, mkbundle

What am I missing here...?

I'm running some sanity tests after installing `mono` on an Ubuntu server (14.04.3 LTS), and hitting some problems when trying to `mkbundle` a simple test app that I got from the mono site.

The test app looks like this:

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    static public void Main ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello Mono World");
    }
}
```

It compiles into `hello.exe` fine when I use `mcs`.

However, when I subsequently run `mkbundle -o hello hello.exe --deps`, this step fails.  The resulting message reads:

```
OS is: Linux
Sources: 1 Auto-dependencies: True
   embedding: /home/admin64/mono-test/hello.exe
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll
Compiling:
as -o temp.o temp.s
sh: 1: as: not found
ERROR: [Fail]
```

This is my first time working with `mkbundle` so I wouldn't be surprised if I missed some critical step. Does anyone have any ideas to this puzzler?

*I'm running with the `mono-complete` package installed.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sh: 1: as: not found`

`mkbundle` is trying to invoke the GNU assembler (`as`) on generated assembly code, after that it will invoke `cc` on generated C code and thus expect to find GCC installed and in your path. I assume you have not installed any other devel packages on that server, otherwise you would have those dependancies installed.

I believe just installing the [`gcc` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc) will give you everything that it needs.

*mkbundle env vars:*

```
AS     Assembler command. The default is "as".
CC     C compiler command. The default is "cc" under Linux and "gcc" under
          Windows.
```